# How to iterate over a xlsx file with multiple comma separated values in cell in to a JSONArray

Tags: java, arraylist, apache-poi

I am reading a xlsx file using java Apache poi util. In which the xlsx file has 3 columns as Teacher, class&Section, Sunbect. The last two columns have multiple comma separated values in the cell. I need to iterate over and construct a JSONArray.

[XLSX sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vF6AW.png)

I have tried some code

```
try {
                    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/Users/HP/Downloads/school.xlsx"));
                    //FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("TestExecution.xlsx"));

                    //HashMap<Integer, Data> mp= new HashMap<Integer, Data>();
                    HashMap<String, List<String>> mp= new HashMap<>();
                    Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);

                    Sheet AddCatalogSheet  = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
                  //Find number of rows in excel file
                    int rowcount = AddCatalogSheet.getLastRowNum()- AddCatalogSheet.getFirstRowNum();
                    System.out.println("Total row number: "+rowcount);
                    for(int i=1; i<rowcount+1; i++){
                        //Create a loop to get the cell values of a row for one iteration
                        Row row = AddCatalogSheet.getRow(i);
                        List<String> arrName = new ArrayList<String>();
                        for(int j=0; j<row.getLastCellNum(); j++){
                            // Create an object reference of 'Cell' class
                            Cell cell = row.getCell(j);
                            switch (cell.getCellType()) 
                            {
                                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                                    //System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t");
                                    arrName.add(NumberToTextConverter.toText(cell.getNumericCellValue()));
                                    break;
                                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                    //System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t");
                                    arrName.add(cell.getStringCellValue());
                                    break;
                            }
                            // Add all the cell values of a particular row
                            
                            }
                        System.out.println(arrName);
                        System.out.println("Size of the arrayList: "+arrName.size());
                        // Create an iterator to iterate through the arrayList- 'arrName'
                        JSONObject teacher = new JSONObject();
                        
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

                        for (int counter = 0; counter < arrName.size(); counter++) {              
                            System.out.println(arrName.get(counter));   
                            jsonArray.put(arrName.get(counter));
                        } 
                        System.out.println(jsonArray.toString()); 
                        }
                        
                    
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

My Expected Result like :

```
[
  {
    "Teacher_code": "23424234",
    "class": [
      {
        "class": "6",
        "section": "A"
      },
      {
        "class": "7",
        "section": "B"
      },
      {
        "class": "8",
        "section": "A"
      }
    ],
    "subject_name": [
      {
        "subject": "Tamil"
      },
      {
        "subject": "English"
      },
      {
        "subject": "Maths"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Please help me to figure out this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think don't use JsonObject inside your code,this will make your code very bloated and difficult to understand. The correct way to do it is to wrap it in a pojo.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        try (InputStream in = Files.newInputStream(Paths.get("E:\\test\\res\\school.xlsx"), READ);
             Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(in)) {
            Sheet sheet  = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

            Row headRow = sheet.getRow(sheet.getFirstRowNum());
            //get first row
            List<String> head = IntStream.range(0, headRow.getLastCellNum())
                    .mapToObj(i -> headRow.getCell(i).getStringCellValue())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

            List<JSONObject> jsonObjects = new ArrayList<>();
            //skip fist row
            for (int i = sheet.getFirstRowNum() + 1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
                Row row = sheet.getRow(i);
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                for (int j = row.getFirstCellNum(); j < row.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
                    Cell cell = row.getCell(j);
                    switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                        case STRING:
                            String strV = cell.getStringCellValue();
                            List<JSONObject> collect = Arrays.stream(strV.split(","))
                                    .map(s -> {
                                        JSONObject classObj = new JSONObject();
                                        if (!s.contains("-")) {
                                            classObj.put("subject", s);
                                            return classObj;
                                        }
                                        String[] classAndSection = s.split("-");
                                        classObj.put("class", classAndSection[0]);
                                        classObj.put("section", classAndSection[1]);
                                        return classObj;
                                    })
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
                            jsonObject.put(head.get(j), collect);
                            break;
                        case NUMERIC:
                            //fix 2.34566E
                            NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
                            nf.setGroupingUsed(false);
                            String format = nf.format(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                            //teacher
                            if (j == row.getFirstCellNum()) {
                                jsonObject.put(head.get(j), format);
                                break;
                            }
                            JSONObject classObj = new JSONObject();
                            classObj.put("class", format);
                            jsonObject.put(head.get(j), classObj);
                            break;
                    }
                }
                jsonObjects.add(jsonObject);
            }
            System.out.println(JSON.toJSONString(jsonObjects));
        }
    }
```

code running result

```
[
  {
    "teacher": "23424234",
    "classAndSection": [
      {
        "section": "A",
        "class": "8"
      },
      {
        "section": "B",
        "class": "9"
      }
    ],
    "subject_name": [
      {
        "subject": "English"
      },
      {
        "subject": "Math"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "teacher": "23424234",
    "classAndSection": {
      "class": "8"
    },
    "subject_name": [
      {
        "subject": "English"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Great work man thanks for the help, the code works fine, and got the expected result